# Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation? Which do you prefer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently looking for a UI framework that will be used on a development of a Booking Engine for Hotel Industry. It must be compatible with mobile devices and desktop, and will be developed in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have only seen simple corporate websites using these frameworks, but nothing robust. Have you already had experiences with both? Which do you prefer and why?

Answer (score 6):

There is no good or bad choice.
I just changed to Foundation 4 from using Bootstrap (I used it for a while...) for client websites, because I better like the "mobile first" approach. My client needs responsive websites, and with bootstrap it takes more time in my opinion.
And one BIG plus to Foundation, you can specify column width to mobile and desktop sizes. It's really useful, when you want to hide a sidebar and fill it's place or change the layout a bit.

On the other hand, I am still using Bootstrap on a large project. And I miss the Affix from Foundation, that's great feature to have.

**Conclusion**: Both are great, it depend on your needs what to choose.

There are great articles on the web about comparison those frameworks, like [this](http://www.webcoursesbangkok.com/blog/bootstrap-2-2-vs-foundation-4-0/)

**Update**: After Bootstrap 3 have been released, I switched back to use it (Bootstrap) and Foundation 5 haven't got any great features or changes, so now I use Bootstrap for every new projects what I have.